# How to show an alert message in ASP.NET Core Razor syntax from PageModel

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, razor

I want to show an alert message to client when an exception is raised in the PageModel. What's the way to achieve this task in ASP.NET Core Razor syntax?

Comment: Do you have in your razor page a line like _<partial name="_StatusMessage" model="Model.StatusMessage" />_?

Comment: @Steve No. What is?

Comment: It is a way to show a message created on the server side (in the cshtml.cs file or the PageModel class) into the cshtml file. It should be something that you get from scaffolding a new Razor Page. Do you have a _StatusMessage.cshtml_ page in your Shared pages folder?

Comment: No I don't. But my intentation is to show an allert like a toast or messagebox...is that possible?

Comment: You can declare a public string property in the PageModel class and leave it empty. When you get an exception you can fill this property with a message of your own and then return to the Page. In the page there is an hidden input field that should linked to the public property. Also you have a javascript code that when the document is ready displays the content of the hidden field. There are many useful javascript libraries that provide a web based MessageBox version like sweetalert2.js

Comment: Basically this approach is what the _StatusMessage_ partial does. Just it shows a boxed div at the top of you page with some background color green or red depending on the content of the model property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a PageModel class where you have declared a variable like this one

```
public class CustomerEditModel() : PageModel
{
    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage {get;set;}
    .....
}
```

Inside this class the Post method finds itself in an exception condition of some type

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
     ....
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Exception in post");
        StatusMessage = "An error occurred while saving customer data!";
        return Page();
     }
}
```

Now in the matching RazorPage you have an hidden field that is linked to the StatusMessage property above

```
<div class="d-none">
   <input asp-for="StatusMessage"/>
</div>
```

finally you add a javascript block that uses JQuery and SweetAlert to display your message box

```
@section Scripts {
<script> src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.1.7/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      let msg = $('#StatusMessage').val();
      if(msg.length > 0) {
          swal.fire(msg);
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bootstrap alert messages.
In Shared>Layout.cshtml add.

```
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @if (TempData[Constants.AlertSuccess] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            @Html.Raw(@TempData[Constants.AlertSuccess])
            </div>
        }
        @if (TempData[Constants.AlertDanger] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            @Html.Raw(@TempData[Constants.AlertDanger])
            </div>
        }
        @if (TempData[Constants.AlertWarning] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            @Html.Raw(@TempData[Constants.AlertWarning])
            </div>
        }
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>
```

In this direction it will work for every page. Otherwise put @if statements in a page of your's choice.

The class Constants

```
public static readonly string AlertSuccess = "AlertSuccess";
public static readonly string AlertDanger = "AlertDanger";
public static readonly string AlertWarning = "AlertWarning";
```

Or write their value directly to TempData. E.g. in OnPost()

```
TempData[Constants.AlertWarning] = "Hello World"
TempData["AlertSuccess"] = "Success<br/>It is good."
TempData["AlertDanger"] = "Danger<br/>It is bad."
```

To display a warning/error/success message to the user.